# Json schema "not in" enum type?

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema

I'd like to use `oneOf` schemas which differ only by value of `xyType` property. I'd like to have two of them: one where the `xyType` is set to `"1"` and the second one where `xyType` is **any other value**. Can this be done using json schemas?

```
"oneOf": [
    {
        "properties": {
            "xyType": "enum": ["1"],
            "whatever" : "string"
        },
        "type": "object"
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "xyType": "enum": [], /// NOT "1"?
            "whatever" : "string"
        },
        "type": "object"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a `not` operator, and the `enum` keyword, and you can use them together, like

```
{
    "not": {
        "enum": ["1"]
    }
}
```